# How to change adnetwork without updating apps on Android

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm afraid if my current adnetwork block me, how can i switch to other adnetwork without updating the app with new ad code .

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, unless you include the SDKs from all the mobile Ad network providers in your project and have a code in your project to call a web service online that you'll have to write to provide it with the ad SDK to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about a particular ad network, then I would suggest using a mediator and including several ad networks that you can choose amongst at runtime. There are many mediators, Admob is one.